# Kubuntu 20.04 installation stuck on "Installation type" screen

Tags: kubuntu, usb-installation

[image: Installation]

I am stuck on the "Installation type" screen during installation of Kubuntu 20.04.

When I click on the "Install now" button, it is loading for roughly 2 seconds (as it is on the image) and then nothing happen, and no error message is supplied.

I have Lenovo Thinkpad x240 with OpenSuse Leap 15.1 and I want to delete the OpenSuse and install Kubuntu or Ubuntu. I have tried use ISO and DD image. Normal installation, checked download updates while installing and also checked third-party software.

Same problem with Ubuntu 20.04 installation.

Comment: Can you confirm this USB install works on other devices? (i.e. not a corrupt download) Furthermore, can you load into a Live Instance and run the installer?

Comment: Dont have any other device to try on. The install is from https://kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/ and also tried from https://kubuntu.org/alternative-downloads/. 
Using Rufus 3.11.
When I just try the system before installation its self, everything works fine.